# Handle all mouse events at once in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have created a button:

```
<button className='collapse-button' onClick={() => {setTopNavigationBarCollapse(!topNavigationBarCollapse)}}>&#9776;</button>
```

I want to call the setState method(setTopNavigationBarCollapse here) on any mouse event that occurs on this button i.e. onMouseEnter, onMouseLeave, onClick etc. Is there a single event handler or do I need to add all of the mouse event handlers on the button?

More info:

state: `const [topNavigationBarCollapse, setTopNavigationBarCollapse] = useState(true);`
setTopNavigationBarCollapse is used to toggle the state.
I do not know any JQuery.

I have tried adding all the mouse event handlers on the button and they work correctly but I have multiple different elements that need to be handled for all the mouse events and I am looking for a neater(dry) way to achieve this.

Comment: there is not a single event for all of those events. however, you can create a function that includes your logic, and pass it to all events needed (onClick, onMouseEnter, onMouseLeave etc.)

Comment: @Arashjahanbakhshan cool thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function YourComponent() {
  const [topNavigationBarCollapse, setTopNavigationBarCollapse] = useState(true);

  const handleMouseEvents = () => {
    setTopNavigationBarCollapse(!topNavigationBarCollapse);
  };

  return (
    <button
      className='collapse-button'
      onClick={handleMouseEvents}
      onMouseEnter={handleMouseEvents}
      onMouseLeave={handleMouseEvents}
    >
      &#9776;
    </button>
  );
}

export default YourComponent;
```

In this code, we define a single handleMouseEvents function that toggles the topNavigationBarCollapse state when called. We then attach this function to the onClick, onMouseEnter, and onMouseLeave events of the button. This approach keeps your code DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) and ensures that the same logic is executed for all of these mouse events on the button.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but I am looking for a handler few specific elements that will get triggered for any event that occurs on them. I can then pass the event object in this handler and determine which event has occurred by using the event.type method and then perform the required action.
@Arashjahanbakshan